# Dealing with Parse Errors when reading in csv via dask.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask-dataframe

I am working with a massive csv file (>3million rows, 76 columns) and have decided to use dask to read the data before converting to a pandas dataframe.

However, I am running into an issue of what looks like column bleeding in the last column. See the code and error below.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd


dataframe = dd.read_csv("SAS url",
                       delimiter = ",", 
                       encoding = "UTF-8", blocksize = 25e6,
                       engine = 'python')
```

Then to see if all the columns are present I use

```py
dataframe.columns
```

When using

```py
dataframe.compute()
```

I see the following error:

[ParseError image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N632h.png)

When using the read_csv parameter `error_bad_lines = False`, it shows that many of the rows have 77 or 78 fields instead of the expected 76.

**Note: Omitting these faulty rows is unfortunately not an option.**

#### Solution I am seeking

Is there a way to keep all the fields and append these extra fields to new columns when necessary?

Comment: What to do depends on WHY those rows have extra "columns".  Is it because they actually have extra values?  Or is it instead that some of the values contain the delimiter character and they are not quoted properly.  If the later then you have a bigger problem with those rows than just a couple of extra values.  With an improperly formatted line you really don't know which values are supposed to go into which variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  You can use the `names=` parameter to add extra columns before you read the full CSV.  I have not tried this with `Dask` but `Dask` `read_csv` calls Pandas `read_csv` under the covers so this should be applicable to `dd.read_csv` as well.

To demonstrate using a simulated CSV file:

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''A,B,C
11,21,31
12,22,32
13,23,33,43,53
14,24,34
15,25,35'''
)
```

By default, `read_csv` fails:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 5
```

Capture the column names:

```
sim_csv.seek(0)    # Not needed for a real CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv, nrows=1)

save_cols = df.columns.to_list()
```

Add a couple column names to the end of the names list and read your CSV:

```
sim_csv.seek(0)    # Not needed for a real CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv, skiprows=1, names=save_cols+['D','E'])

df

    A   B   C     D     E
0  11  21  31   NaN   NaN
1  12  22  32   NaN   NaN
2  13  23  33  43.0  53.0
3  14  24  34   NaN   NaN
4  15  25  35   NaN   NaN
```